# BoundField style

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

How can I give style for BoundField?

I'm using BoundField in Gridview. Tt shows an underline and an unwanted color.

How do I remove underline and color?

Answer (score 9):

Depending on what bound field you are trying it might vary a little but here is an example. Each fields has properties for various styles and you can set `CssClass` as well.

## CommandField

```css
.select {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Red;
}
```

```html
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True">
    <ControlStyle CssClass="select" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

## BoundField

```css
.product {
    color: Blue;
}
```

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="product">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="product" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

---

Go to `GridView` Properties → Columns and you will find all your fields listed there. There you can set the [style properties of `BoundField`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx)

Another alternative is using a Template Field where you will have more control.

Comment: ItemStyle-CssClass worked for me, thanks. I was using ControlStyle-CssClass.